# how to draw automatic poligon shape from an sprite with alpha ? for an box2d tool

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, osx-mountain-lion

I have started a new project, that will help creating a game from scratch, with just a few lines of code.
I won't make advertising here, because this is not that kind of site, but i will ask a few questions.

So the tool will take over the most apps that were helping on making a game, it will be one app to rulle them all ( or maybe, it will run only with cocos2d and box2d ).

So, first i need to make the tool to be able to draw a polygon shape for the image ( to create the bodys for box2d ), this it must be done ( as you already figured ) with out selecting also the alpha channels.

I can try on holding each pixel on 2 arrays, and then check for the pixel channels, if they contain alpha <= 0.3, than the pixel will be ignored, then if the alpha is >= 0.3 store the pixel in an array then later after i have checked all the pixels I will create the shape with the vertices int those pixels that are at the edge of the shape ( another loop is required to check the edge pixels ).

**Question**: is this a good approach ? or is there another better way ?

I want the tool to be extremely light, with high performance, like every apple software, this is the reason that i ask, because if i am going to make this tool, then i want to make it great!
thanks for reading, i hope someone can give me a good answer.

Comment: PhysicsEditor already does that. Check of it satisfies your needs.

Comment: ok, so first of all, i want to build my own tool, because non of the available tools on the market satisfies me. So i'm just asking if i am using a good approach... Then what a game engineer am i, if i'm not building my own tools ?!

Comment: @AiU: What does not satisfy you in the PhysicsEditor? Reinventing the bicycle is not something that makes you a good developer.

Comment: Physic editor is a great tool, but its past his life.

Comment: think, just sprite helper does all the job that your apps does. Look at the apple, maybe you can learn something from them, then you will understand what is the problem with your apps.

Comment: Back in 2004 or 2005 i was downloading a lot of funky videos from internet using an app call LimeWire ( similar to a torrent ), but some times a video could take up to a week or 2. Then i have fought "God, with all of this engineers in the world, smart people that made the college as software engineer, why don't hey build a way to visualise videos directly from the browser page, and while the video is downloading on the computer ( as any normal page ) the video should be displayed and you can

Comment: already see the video, at least the downloaded part". 6 months later i discover youtube. Imagine that i didn't even knew what "coding language was" at that time. So now i have a similar idea! And first of all, i develop this for my self, then for the general public. Now can i have my blody answer ?